# Merging calendars in Outlook Exchange

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

My organization uses MS Exchange in order to share information. One powerful feature that I find useful is the ability to view if a another person is busy/free at a given time. However, I have multiple calendars I use to better organize myself.

It looks like I can only make one calendar view able by the rest of my organization. Is there a way to automatically add events to this shared calendar when I add it to any of my other calendars?

Thanks

Comment: If you have multiple calendars doesn't that mean you have multiple accounts?  Deal with Exchange daily, I don't see, how to create more than one calendar connected to exchange

Comment: @Ramhound If you switch to Outlook's folder view, then create a new calendar, it will be in the user's mailbox and can be shared just like the default calendar.

Comment: @Allen You *can* have and share multiple calendars with other users, though I am unsure if this will effect your free/busy data which may be based on your primary calendar alone. I doubt you're looking for a different way to organize, but if you're open to ideas, you could use a single calendar and use categories to segregate your events, then create separate views that filter by category, producing the "separate calendar" views you currently have. This would avoid requiring your co-workers having to connect to multiple of your calendars.

Comment: Otherwise, to create an event on one calendar and populate it on another will require VBA, which will only work on devices running the VBA code, which you'll need to manually copy between devices if any changes are made.

Comment: A Outlook plugin that syncs multiple calendars to a single calendar seems like the simplest solution or use categories :-) if your not a programmer

Comment: @Twisty I actually started using categories but found them incredibly limiting. The mobile app doesn't support viewing or editing them. I have yet to find an IPhone app that supports categories, otherwise I would definitely consider using them. VBA is not ideal because you need to copy the code to each device you use. If you know of an exchange plugin that does this, do you mind linking it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I hear you on all points. I'm not aware of an add-on that handles this. It's worth pointing out (most) mobile calendar apps only permit access to your default Exchange calendar, which could be a problem when multiple calendars are in use. Some time back I used Symantec's [TouchDown](https://www.symantec.com/theme/touchdown) email app which did support a lot more features. It might handle multiple calendars and/or categories.

Comment: @Twisty My current system is just using the default apply calendar app and subscribing to each of my 3 calendars. That way they are loosely organized into personal, work, and school. In outlook, I suborganize school into classes with categories. It isn't ideal, but at least this way its still kind of color coded in apple calendar. However, it presents obvious issues in terms of free/busy information.

Comment: Do your co-workers have permissions to your additional calendars? You can grant them permissions by right-clicking the calendar> Properties then go to the Permissions tab. There you can grant them access to that calendar's free/busy information. Perhaps that solves your problem?